# "Duffel" or "duffle"

Tags: orthography

I'm seeing an either/or in most dictionaries I've checked with regard to *duffel* and *duffle* when used to refer to coats and bags. It seems to come from a Belgian town spelled *Duffel*.

What's your take? I'd like to be definitive.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffel_bag) both spellings are correct

> A duffel bag (or duffle bag, kit bag, gym bag) is a large cylindrical bag made of cloth (or other fabric) with a drawstring closure at the top.

On the other hand [Google NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=duffel%20bag,duffle%20bag&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) [image: Google NGram] shows, that first spelling is more common in the last couple of decades. So just to be safe I'd use the *duffel bag* spelling.

P.S. Funny thing is that there are both Duffel Bags and Duffle Bag company and both are producing... that same bags :)

Comment: However, the [duffel coat,duffle coat Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=duffel+coat%2Cduffle+coat&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows *duffle coat* is first and more popular. If you switch to the [American English corpus](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=duffel+coat%2Cduffle+coat&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3), *duffle coat* is now more popular.

Comment: Thanks - I like Duffel. It's the original, and the populace prefers it. Decision made.

Comment: I’ve always thought of ‘duffle’ as the BrEng spelling, but in the same year, 1957, Colin MacInnes had ‘duffel’ and Muriel Spark had ‘duffle’.

Answer (score 4):

[CALD](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/duffel-bag?q=duffel) and [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/duffel) list both spellings as possible with *duffel* as the primary entry. [Etmyonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=duffle&allowed_in_frame=0) says of *duffle*

> 1670s, from Du. duffel, from Duffel, town in Brabant where the cloth
>   was originally sold. Duffel bag is Amer.Eng., first recorded 1917 in a
>   letter of e e cummings.

It probably started off with *duffel* and later *duffle* came to be used as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used "duffel" for the coat & "duffle" for the bag.